# GetPixel on DirectX Application

Tags: delphi, directx, getpixel

I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XYCoord: integer;
  window: hwnd;
  c: TCanvas;
  result : TColor;
  color : string;
begin
  c := TCanvas.Create;
  window := FindWindow('Atlantica Online', NIL);
  try
    c.Handle := GetWindowDC(window);
    Result   := GetPixel(c.Handle, 50, 10);
  finally
    c.Free;
  end;
  color := GetColorASRGBString(result, true);
  if color = '#FF0000' then
  begin
    SendMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, makelong(50, 10));
    SendMessage(window, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, makelong(50, 10));
  end;
end;

function TForm1.GetColorASRGBString(
  const ColorToConvert : TColor;
  const IncludePrefixChar: Boolean): String;
var
  r,g,b         : Byte;
  CurrentColor  : TColor;
  HexColorWithSpaces : String;
const
  HexFormatStr  : String = '%2x';
begin
  CurrentColor  := ColorToConvert;

  CurrentColor  := ColorToRGB(CurrentColor);
  r := GetRValue(CurrentColor);
  g := GetGValue(CurrentColor);
  b := GetBValue(CurrentColor);

  HexColorWithSpaces := IfThen(IncludePrefixChar, '#','')
    + Format(HexFormatStr, [r])
    + Format(HexFormatStr, [g])
    + Format(HexFormatStr, [b]);
  Result := AnsiReplaceStr(HexColorWithSpaces, ' ', '0');
end;
```

If a give pixel on a given window is red (255,0,0) it should click there...

Works very fine for every normal application...

But if an application uses DirectX it fails (returns black (#000000))...

Are there any solutions for this without need to hook the directx?

Thanks in advance

Comment: my inbox shows me 2 comments.. why i can't see them? :(

Comment: That was me saying you, that you'll need to use DirectX function since GDI function can't access a DirectX drawing buffers because they works in a different level, but I've deleted them later...

Comment: Means, i would really have to hook the DirectX functions of the application where i want to read the pixels, copy the buffer and then search this one?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Assign that DC to your canvas and you should be good.
A bit of googling will give you lots of information about IDirect3DSurface9::GetDC.

Comment: But... finally need to hook this function cause i don't want the DirectX output of my own but from an other application...